# How do NFT marketplaces work? (Mostly about authorization of transferring NFTs)

Tags: solidity, nft, markets

ERC721 says that NFTs can only be transferred by owners/authorized addresses. How are solidity marketplace contracts made to allow a third party address to transfer an NFT from your account to theirs since they would need to be authorized to transfer that NFT

Answer (score 0):

You will understand the whole process better once you do it by own. I will recommend this for experimenting: [ERC721-Redroad](https://github.com/akcgjc007/ERC721-Redroad)

When we want to sell an NFT on a third party platform, we have to transfer the ownership of the ERC721 token to this third party, so that it can sell to buyers.

**None of the third party is allowed to transfer the ownership of your NFT**.